# How to SELECT two columns, where one column must be DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql

`Table1` has 3 columns: `col1`, `col2`, `col3`

How can I `SELECT` all the `DISTINCT` values of `col1` where `col3` equals a certain value, then sort it by `col2 DESC`, yet have the distinct `col1` results show their corresponding `col2` value?

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (col1), col2
FROM  `Table1` 
WHERE  `col3` =  'X'
ORDER BY  `col2` DESC
```

The above does not result in distinct values of `col1`.  If I remove "`, col2`", then it will show distinct values of `col1`, but it won't show me their corresponding `col2` values.

So how do I do it?

Comment: `select distinct` applies to the entire row, not individual fields.

Comment: which value do you want from Col2 ? as there will be lots of different values for each col1 ?

Comment: @Marc B, thanks, but then how do I show all the columns of that entire row?

Comment: @ManseUK, I want the largest value of col2 for each distinct col1.

Comment: @Programmer Use sub query for col1's distinct value seprately, see my answer may it helps.

Comment: @Programmer: `select *`, or list all of the fields in the query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) col2_max
FROM Table1
WHERE col3 = 'X'
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col2_max
```

?

You can play with it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c855/5).

Comment: All that's missing form this answer is adding `DESC` after `ORDER BY col2_max`, but this worked!  I knew there had to be a simple and straightforward solution.  I'm awarding you the answer because you also introduced me to SQL Fiddle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure mySQL supports the `GROUP BY` clause, and given you want the *greatest* value of `col2`, this should get you the results you want:

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) as col2
FROM Table1
WHERE col3 = 'X'
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want greatest `col2` for each `col1`:

```
SELECT  tm.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT col1
        FROM    table1
        WHERE   col3 = 'X'
        ) t
JOIN    table tm
ON      id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    table1 ti
        WHERE   ti.col3 = 'X'
                AND ti.col1 = t.col1
        ORDER BY
                col2 DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) col2
ORDER BY
        col2 DESC
```

Create an index on `(col3, col1, col2)` for this to work fast.

**Update:**

If you only need these two columns, the query can indeed be made more simple:

```
SELECT  col1, MAX(col2) AS maxcol2
FROM    table1
WHERE   col3 = 'X'
GROUP BY
        col1
ORDER BY
        maxcol2 DESC
```

But if you need the whole record (along with the additional fields possbily contained in the table), you would need the initial syntax.

Comment: Wow, please excuse my ignorance, but does something so simple require such a complicated query?  Is there no way to just tell MySQL to return the DISTINCT(col1) ordered by col2 DESC, and then just show the corresponding col3 values for each row?

Comment: @programmer: if you have two records with the same `col1` but different `col2`, which record should the query return?

Comment: @Programmer: nevermind, saw your comment to the original post. Yes, it does require such a complicated query. In `PostgreSQL` you could use `DISTINCT ON` (which does exactly what you want), in `Oracle 8i+` and `SQL Server 2005+` (and `PostgreSQL 8.4+`) you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`. In `MySQL`, you need this.

Comment: your original query worked and only returned the 2 columns I needed, but was very slow (you mentioned it needed a multiple index, so I'm sure it could be made faster with that).  However, your updated simplified query only returns ONE row, the row with the highest col2 value.  Could you please fix it?  Thanks. (By the way, I didn't downvote you, I'm the one that upvoted your original query.)

Comment: I see that it's the solution provided below by Branko, which I tested and it worked.  I had the feeling there had to be a more simple way of doing this, and I'm glad there is as it makes my life easier. :)  I must award the solution to him, but I really appreciate all your help with this query.  You are an asset to this community!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t.col1, max(t.col2)
  FROM Table1 t
 WHERE t.col3='X'
 GROUP BY t.col1
 ORDER BY t.col2 DESC;
```

**EDIT:** This answer have had several revisions, keeping the most accurate one.

Comment: This will just return all records with `col3 = 'X'`

Comment: -1 - This will not return disctinct rows, as multiple similar values in the outer query will match the single value returned in the subquery.  SQL is set-based, and isn't going to 'remove' the row after it has been used.

Comment: @X-Zero: actually, this one will return what the op has asked for (except that it is unnecessarily complex and the nested query is redundant).

Comment: Wierd, I could have sworn it didn't have that `GROUP BY` earlier.  @vyegorov, if you could edit the question, I'll remove the downvote - you're over-complicating things anyways.

Comment: @X-Zero, I know, as what it is now is a result of another edit. If I simplify it, it will actually match with your answer. I will vote for deleting it in fact, too much confusion.

Comment: @vyegorov - That's okay, just perform the edit, don't worry about deleting it - multiple identical answers are acceptable, and tend to show up anways.  In some ways, you were heading towards the 'correct' version before I showed up anyways.