# Get two columns from single table where one is max and group by that max column

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table: XYZ
+----+-----------+--------+---------+
| ID | parent_ID | status | user_ID |
+----+-----------+--------+---------+
| 1  | 432       | public | 23      |
| 5  | 432       | public | 1       |
| 10 | 432       | public | 14      |
| 24 | 432       | public | 4       |
+----+-----------+--------+---------+
```

If this is the scenario where `ID` is an *auto increment* field I can grab the last ID by the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM XYZ
WHERE parent_ID = 432
   AND status = 'public'
```

How can I grab the two fields: `ID`, and `user_ID` using a single query so that I can have the following result:

```
array(
   'ID' => 24
   'user_ID' => 4
)
```

That means the Maximum value of `ID` where `parent_ID` is 432 and `user_ID` of that row of `ID`.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10301461/1743124) and tried, but in my case I don't have group by `ID` and max `ID` different. In my case everything is `ID`. I know I can have them all, then can run a foreach to grab the max one in PHP way, but I think a single SQL query is much faster here.

Any help and suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Umm, `SELECT ID, user_UD FROM XYZ WHERE ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM XYZ WHERE parent_ID = 432 AND status = 'public');`?

Comment: Isn't that equal to a double query? Is that performance-savvy?

Comment: Its a subquery. Probably better than 2 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, user_ID
FROM XYZ AS x
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID
            FROM XYZ
            WHERE parent_ID = 432 AND status = 'public') t
ON x.ID = t.maxID
```

Or, alternatively:

```
SELECT ID, user_ID
FROM XYZ 
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID
            FROM XYZ
            WHERE parent_ID = 432 AND status = 'public')
```

Comment: Thank you. I need expert comment, whether these types of query is faster or should I implement a single query as I mentioned and then use PHP to sort out things.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam If your table is properly indexed then using one of the above queries is definitely preferable over transferring the whole table from the DB Server.